# how to get MAC address of any mobile phone via bluetooth connection in c#?

Tags: c#, mobile, bluetooth

I have to first establish a connection between mobile phone and computer then i have to get a MAC address of that connected phone when i will get a MAC address then i have to simply disconnect the current device and search for the other device.

please help me to solve this problem........... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the recent Windows Mobile SDKs and DTKs, there's a sample app called **btsearch** that enumerates all Bluetooth devices that are discoverable and within range. You could always start from there and pick what looks interesting.

I've used it successfully myself without problems. Although it only shows the basics, it's easy to build upon it and extract the good bits.

Comment: I have another problem now. Im using <bluetoothAPIs.h> header file in visual C++ but i got that error (Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _BluetoothFindRadioClose@4 referenced in function _wmain) like this there are almost 8 errors. please sir can u tell me whats the problem.

Comment: @ahsan: You need to add `bthprops.lib` to your library dependencies.