# Can WP8.1 be able to read the connected device‘s Bluetooth MAC address?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, windows-phone

Being a Windows Phone's Beginner developer, I want to read the connected device's Bluetooth MAC address in C#.

This sounds very easy, but I can't figure it out. So this is a part of my App progress:

After reading the connected device's MAC address, the backstage will take this address to match the MySQL's data, and if matched the App could take next step.

After reading many books even in MSDN I still cannot find this solution.
Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829346/how-to-get-mac-address-of-any-mobile-phone-via-bluetooth-connection-in-c

Comment: @NSNoob thanks for your link!I will read those samples and try solved this question again!

Comment: If you manage to solve it, do post the solution here. It will help others looking for a similar answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's help,especially @NSNoob !

After searching MSDN's documents,I finally the solution!

```
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
    }

    void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Bluetooth is not available in the emulator. 
        if (Microsoft.Devices.Environment.DeviceType == Microsoft.Devices.DeviceType.Emulator)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(AppResources.Msg_EmulatorMode,"Warning",MessageBoxButton.OK);
        }

        _pairedDevices = new ObservableCollection<PairedDeviceInfo>();
        PairedDevicesList.ItemsSource = _pairedDevices;
    }

    private void FindPairedDevices_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshPairedDevicesList();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Asynchronous call to re-populate the ListBox of paired devices.
    /// </summary>
    private async void RefreshPairedDevicesList()
    {
        try
        {
            // Search for all paired devices
            PeerFinder.AlternateIdentities["Bluetooth:Paired"] = "";
            var peers = await PeerFinder.FindAllPeersAsync();

            // By clearing the backing data, we are effectively clearing the ListBox
            _pairedDevices.Clear();

            if (peers.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(AppResources.Msg_NoPairedDevices);
            }
            else
            {
                // Found paired devices.
                foreach (var peer in peers)
                {
                    _pairedDevices.Add(new PairedDeviceInfo(peer));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x8007048F)
            {
                var result = MessageBox.Show(AppResources.Msg_BluetoothOff, "Bluetooth Off", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
                if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
                {
                    ShowBluetoothcControlPanel();
                }
            }
            else if ((uint)ex.HResult == 0x80070005)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(AppResources.Msg_MissingCaps);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ConnectToSelected_Tap_1(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        // Because I enable the ConnectToSelected button only if the user has
        // a device selected, I don't need to check here whether that is the case.

        // Connect to the device
        PairedDeviceInfo pdi = PairedDevicesList.SelectedItem as PairedDeviceInfo;
        PeerInformation peer = pdi.PeerInfo;

        // Asynchronous call to connect to the device
        ConnectToDevice(peer);
    }

    private async void ConnectToDevice(PeerInformation peer)
    {
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            // Disposing the socket with close it and release all resources associated with the socket
            _socket.Dispose();
        }

        try
        {
            _socket = new StreamSocket();
            string serviceName = (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(peer.ServiceName)) ? tbServiceName.Text : peer.ServiceName;

            // Note: If either parameter is null or empty, the call will throw an exception
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(peer.HostName, serviceName);

            // If the connection was successful, the RemoteAddress field will be populated
           MessageBox.Show(String.Format(AppResources.Msg_ConnectedTo, _socket.Information.RemoteAddress.DisplayName));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // In a real app, you would want to take action dependent on the type of 
            // exception that occurred.
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

            _socket.Dispose();
            _socket = null;
        }
    }

    private void PairedDevicesList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check whether the user has selected a device
        if (PairedDevicesList.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            // No - hide these fields
            ConnectToSelected.IsEnabled = false;
            ServiceNameInput.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else
        {
            // Yes - enable the connect button
            ConnectToSelected.IsEnabled = true;

            // Show the service name field, if the ServiceName associated with this device is currently empty
            PairedDeviceInfo pdi = PairedDevicesList.SelectedItem as PairedDeviceInfo;
            ServiceNameInput.Visibility = (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pdi.ServiceName)) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    private void ShowBluetoothcControlPanel()
    {
        ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();
        connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = ConnectionSettingsType.Bluetooth;
        connectionSettingsTask.Show();
    }
}

/// <summary>
///  Class to hold all paired device information
/// </summary>
public class PairedDeviceInfo
{
    internal PairedDeviceInfo(PeerInformation peerInformation)
    {
        this.PeerInfo = peerInformation;
        this.DisplayName = this.PeerInfo.DisplayName;
        this.HostName = this.PeerInfo.HostName.DisplayName;
        this.ServiceName = this.PeerInfo.ServiceName;
    }

    public string DisplayName { get; private set; }
    public string HostName { get; private set; }
    public string ServiceName { get; private set; }
    public PeerInformation PeerInfo { get; private set; }
}
```

}

You can also download this sample through this linK:https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/ff402535(v=vs.105).aspx